# Calendar date picker - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use this date picker in the link below **(date 3 script)**.

http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php

It shows me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'tc_calendar' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\a.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\a.php on line 5
```

What should I do to correct it?

Thanks

here is a.php script:

```
<html>
<head><script language="javascript" src="calendar.js"></script></head>
<body>
<?php
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true, false);
      $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
      $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
      $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
      $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2000, 2017);
      $myCalendar->dateAllow('2008-05-13', '2017-03-01');
      $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
      $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');
      $myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-01", "2011-04-04", "2011-12-25"), 0, 'year');
      $myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-04-10", "2011-04-14"), 0, 'month');
      $myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("2011-06-01"), 0, '');
      $myCalendar->writeScript();


?>
<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">
<?php
//get class into the page
require_once('classes/tc_calendar.php');

//instantiate class and set properties
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true);

$myCalendar->setDate(1, 1, 2000);

//output the calendar
$myCalendar->writeScript();   

?>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you provide content of `a.php` ?

Comment: @timiTao i just added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't import the class `tc_calendar`. 
Todo so you need to download the tc_calendar and place it in your solution.

Then you need to include the php class with for example an `include()`;

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you require calendar php file in your a.php before use it?

```
require_once('classes/tc_calendar.php');
```

If so, don't you give the wrong path to the file?

Comment: sorry i didn't get the path thing, is the file 'classes' should be inside the directory where i keep all the scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You have to require first your "tc_calendar.php" file before starting to use it ,and let it the first line directly after starting the php tag for example :

```
<?php 
//get class into the page
require_once('classes/tc_calendar.php');
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true, false);
```

Comment: This will help you importing  all your Class variables  from your "tc_calendar.php" file, then deal with them lately.